# Calculate foldersize exlude files hardlink

Tags: bash, unix, rsync, du

I'm using a bash script with rsync to create daily and weekly backups. How it works in short:

- the script sets up variables for the days and weeks.
- current day folder gets emptied: `rm -rf /path/to/$currentday/*`
- Previous day content gets copied to current day (hardlinks): `cp -ral /path/to/$previousday/* /path/to/$currentday/`
- the script then syncs the changes made: `rsync -tru --progress /path/to/SOURCE/* /path/to/$currentday/`

This is being pulled from one Storage device to Another over WAN. Since the company is growing we need to monitor how much data actually is being sent over WAN every time the script runs.

Is there a way for me to calculate the `$currentday` folder and exclude the files that didn't change (still hardlinked)?

Or maybe add a line to the script that log the files being sent?

I've been searching the internet but unfortunately didn't find anything useful, everything I try comes up with the total size of the folder, which is 2TB.

Did someone do this who is willing to share this with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observed that `du` has the hability to count the size of hardlinks just once. Test this steps:

```
mkdir 1 2
cd 1
dd if=/dev/zero of=f1 bs=1024 count=1024
dd if=/dev/zero of=f2 bs=1024 count=2048
cd ../2
ln ../1/f1
cp ../1/f2 .
cd ..
du -shc 1 2
du -shc 2 1
```

You will see that the second folder doesn't take into account the size of hardlinks previously used. Perhaps this approach is of some help.